# How to host my application (MEAN) on amazon EC2 Linux instance?

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have developed an application on Ionic 2 and Angular2 with MongoDB as database and Node.js and Express.js as a server. I have created database on my laptop as `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db')`.

Now, I have launched an AWS EC2 Linux instance and installed node and npm packages.

Successfully cloned my application with git repo in EC2 Linux instance and installed mongodb server and connected to the shell of my laptop's mongoDB by commenting `bindip` in `mongod.conf` file.

Now when I am running `node server.js` in the EC2 instance is reads the `console.log(App listining to port 8080')` which is present just below `app.listen(8080)` in **server.js** file. After that nothing gets happened.

1. How can I connect the server mongodb to the db that I have created on my laptop with the application as localhost, i.e `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db')`?

For reference, I am attaching my **server.js** file

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/reviewking');

app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' }));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-control-Allow-Method", "DELETE,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

//Models

var Review = mongoose.model('Review', {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    rating: Number

});

//Routes

app.get('/api/reviews', function (req, res) {
    console.log('fetching reviews..');

    Review.find(function (err, reviews) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(reviews);
    });

});

app.post('/api/reviews',function(req,res){
    console.log('creating reviews');

    //create a review

    Review.create({
        title: req.body.title,
        description:req.body.description,
        rating:req.body.rating,
        done:false
    }, function(err, reviews){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);

        Review.find(function(err,reviews){
            if(err)
            res.send(err);
            res.json(reviews);
        });      
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('app listening on port 8080')
```

Comment: Do you want your EC2 instance to connect to the mongodb running on your laptop or do you want to know how to copy your mongodb database to EC2?

Comment: How to copy my mongodb database to EC2...Connecting the EC2 instance to mongodb I have done.But my laptop's database is different and EC2 db is different.

Comment: you can either do it by using software like Mongo chef or can export all your data in a folder upload it on EC2 and import those files over there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to run [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/), upload the dump to your server (probably use [scp](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)) and restore using [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/).

```
# Backup the reviewking database (on your laptop)
mongodump --db reviewking

# Restore the reviewking database (on your server)
mongorestore --db reviewking dump/reviewking
```